# Как использовать Font Awesome в Adobe XD

Tags: adobexd

Как подключить или использовать иконочные шрифты в Adobe XD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо их установить в компьютер.
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases - тут можно скачать десткоп версию.
После этого шрифт можно будет использовать.

Конкретно с этим шрифтом так не делал, но с другими делал именно так.